# mp4 video not uploading to website properly? HTML5 Video Tag not working

Tags: html, video, mp4

I'm uploading a mp4 video and a wmv video to my sub-domain within my companies website. Next: I go to the mp4 url and get "The page cannot be found". Next: I go to the wmv url and the file begins to download immediately. Sketchy?

So I'm using the video tag like this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Here's the result (it shows nothing):
http://rstillman.telicfootwear.com/telicretail.html

Research has taught me to change my web.config file but then I just end up with parse errors

> Parse Unrecognized configuration section system.webServer.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem?  The movie doesn't run because the source of the movie (http://rstillman.telicfootwear.com/movie.mp4) doesn't exist... hence it doesn't play.

Are you sure you uploaded it to that exact location?

Comment: Yes I tried to convey that. My FTP software reads that the file is indeed there. Here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/QsMUnM0.png

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded the file to the correct path within the webserver then I would check that you have a MIME Type defined for the file type.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=WS.10).aspx for instructions, and you'll need to make sure you have added `mp4` as the extension and `video/mp4` as the MIME Type.

If you intend also serving other video types (webm, ogg) then you'll also need to add their MIME type entries

Comment: "Parse Unrecognized configuration section system.webServer." is what I get when I try to change the Web.config file as per the last bit of my post

Comment: which would mean the change you're making isn't correct. Follow the instructions above (or paste in the change you're making to the config)

Comment: please share the mime types you have added to your config... or use the gui to add .mp4

Comment: weird. that looks right. what version of IIS are you running (this is only IIS7 and above). Have you tried added via the GUI, and restarting the server?

Comment: Turns out we are on IIS6.5 in our box! We are upgrading though... =) thanks for your help.